# Extract next page link using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox module

Tags: javascript, perl, firefox, navigation, mechanize

I am trying to scrape a asp site, where when I try to navigate to the next page the link shows in the source code is:

```
<a href="javascript: GoToPage(2); ">Next »</a>
```

I use regular expressions to extract content, I am not able to get the next page link.

Comment: Just use `$mech->click`.

Comment: the action click is not waiting for the page , its getting clicked before the page gets loaded.

Comment: See the `$mech->synchronize` method in the documentation.